# Dynamic props in vnode doesn't work, in elementui

Tags: node.js, vue.js, element-ui

I want to use a dynamic prop in vnode, but it doesn't work

```
const h = this.$createElement;

this.$notify({
  message: h('el-progress', {
    props: {
      percentage: this.percentage,
    },
  }),
  duration: 0,
  customClass: 'download-progress-container',
});

setInterval(() => {
  this.percentage += 1;
}, 1000);
```

I expect the progress bar 's percentage changed as the parent's prop, but it doesn't